# cant install any python package (maybee due to urllib3 changes)

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I tried to install xgboost with pip but got the error (and after any installation ends up with this error) `"ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname"`

I reinstall Anaconda - no results. Install new version of urllib3 from whl - no results. My python version if 3.9. pip 21.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some proxy software like V2ray or some VPN? If yes then try closing them.

For example you might be using the proxy setting from windows:

[image: Windows proxy setting]

Comment: thank you so much. For some reason (I dont know) proxy was on. Off helps then